# Cannot declare molar units

Tags: siunitx

I am trying to overwrite the small cap on `\Molar` to be a normal cap M and I cannot seem to change it. I have tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros} 
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\DeclareSIUnit[]\Molar{M}
% Or
\DeclareSIUnit{\Molar}{M}
% Or
\DeclareSIUnit{\Molar}{\textup{M}}

\begin{document}

\SI{0.1}{\Molar}

\end{document}
```

I even tried to change `\molar` to M using the same methods and it doesn't change it from it's default.

Is the `\DeclareSIUnit` not working on these units or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Cross-posted as a bug report: https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/279

Comment: Yes, he fixed it for me.  Please refer to that github link for the solution.

Comment: With v5.0 (2015/09/11) of `chemmacros` the example should work as expected because `chemmacros` units module isn't loaded per default any more

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that `chemmacros` defines `\Molar` as a small caps 'M'. This can be over-ridden by applying your settings using the `\AtBeginDocument` hook

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros} 
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\AtBeginDocument{
  \DeclareSIUnit[]\Molar{M}
}

\begin{document}

\SI{0.1}{\Molar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there an official way for checking if a unit is already defined? (Actually a `\ProvideSIUnit` would be nice for `chemmacros`…)

Comment: @clemens No but that's 'by design' really: I understand why you've added `\Molar` to `chemmacros` but I'd much rather non-SI units were declared on a per document basis.

Comment: I'm not sure I would still add them to `chemmacros` today… At least in version 5 users will have to load `chemmacros`' “units” module explicitly to get those